# Are there primitive Pythagoras triplets (in integers), being with all the terms as powerful numbers?

Tags: mathematics, biographical-details, number-theory, pythagorean-proposition

I'm searching a trusted historical sources about primitive Pythagoras triplets as being powerful integers (numerical examples), or a notable work of impossibility of such a triples, but couldn't find despite asking this question here at MSE and MOF

I do expect some old references for this issue, as when and who stated this issue, and what are the consequences of this problem on the important unsolved problems in mathematics

Please if any information available, provide exact dates with references.

Comment: *I do expect some old references for this issue*—depending on what is considered 'old', of course, but it seems to me that powerful numbers weren't considered before the 1930s...? By the way, [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1836372/12885) is the (OPs) MSE-question asking whether primitive Pythagorean triples consisting of powerful numbers only can exist.

Comment: Pythagorean triples are old in history even before Pythagoras, I think the oldest are during Babelyons old civilizations (Iraq nowadays), but we don't know for sure wither all their properties are discovered, if the suggested (most likely new property is established), then so much bless to mathematics, and if it is refuted (by a single counter example), then nothing would be lost at all, it seems to me that we are in need of the help of supercomputer first, then we can talk about it more seriously !

Comment: In fact, Pythagorean triples are under consideration for a very long time, but (to my knowledge) powerful numbers weren't.

Comment: Actually, if we assume this is an established fact, then few unsolved problems would be an immediate results, but the proof of this conjecture also seems so simple as claimed or may be so difficult as unsolved problems, let me arrange one proof once I complete it soon, the conjecture itself is very interesting since it should had been noted long ago, (but we hope it fails completely), the interesting result would be so surprising since it would prove Beal's conjecture as well, powerful triplet is indeed so powerful approach to many unsolved problems I think!

Comment: @SophyanGharz Thanks for you to activate this unsolved problem, which is relevant to the most famous fact in mathematics, that is Pythagoras theorem, however it would be very nice of you if you can prove it, but be aware that there are better places for such proof than here, I guess also many secretly had known the simple trick for this puzzle, so let them enjoy secretly the discovering sense of great puzzles for a while, actually soon there would be so many of them hunting the secret at nearly the same time, and of course the remaining parts are not so interesting, but would be hurting badly

Comment: @bassamkarzeddin I don't expect anyone knows the suitable answer for this say conjecture would simply add it here, since you know better the reasons!, actually solving this seemingly so simple question in number theory is not less important than solving few unsolved problems together in mathematics that are standing as a challenge for so many centuries, and your problem is equally so hard to prove I think!  so let alone the future answer it, otherwise many would have come up with easy proofs, because mathematicians love the challenging problems, but what was so strange is the Pythagoras link.

Comment: https://www.quora.com/Can-you-find-a-right-angle-triangle-with-coprime-integer-sides-x-3-y-2-z/answer/Bassam-Karzeddin-1,